# Parsing trends.json from Twitter Search API

Tags: php, twitter

Struggling to parse this JSON response from http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json

using `foreach ($json_output->trends[0] as $trend )
    {
        echo $trend->name;
    }`

```
stdClass Object ( [trends] => stdClass Object ( [2011-05-03 17:43:42] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [query] => TeAmamosLuanS [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => TeAmamosLuanS ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [query] => CASEY RULES [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => CASEY RULES ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [query] => Rashard Mendenhall [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => Rashard Mendenhall ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [query] => Alexandre Nardoni [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => Alexandre Nardoni ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [query] => Henrique Capriles [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => Henrique Capriles ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [query] => LivroRestart [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => LivroRestart ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [query] => TeamXtina [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => TeamXtina ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [query] => Howard Webb [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => Howard Webb ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [query] => Camp Nou [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => Camp Nou ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [query] => MTV Movie Awards [events] => [promoted_content] => [name] => MTV Movie Awards ) ) ) [as_of] => 1304444622 )
```

Please help with array/object parsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
<?php
$json_output = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json"));
foreach ($json_output->trends as $datetime=>$vals ) {
    echo "As of $datetime the trends are:<br />";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($vals as $trend)
        echo "<li>{$trend->name}</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Output:

> As of 2011-05-03 22:07:58 the trends
>   are:
>
> - #onethingiveneverdone
> - #turnon
> - #pssst
> - Irn Bru
> - Justin Bieberon
> - Pobre Messi
> - Derrick Rose MVP
> - Shania Twain
> - Rashard Mendenhall
> - LatinBeliebersASKDates